# How to check if object is instanceof firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

On the firebase js web client:

```
var fv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
var sv = fv.serverTimestamp();

sv instanceof fv //true
```

whereas in node:

```
var fb = require('firebase-admin');
var fv = fb.firestore.FieldValue;
var sv = fv.serverTimestamp();

sv instanceof fv //false
```

I don't know why there's this inconsistency. How can i tell if an object is an instance of firebase.firestore.FieldValue? It needs to work for both node and js web.

### edit

Some context. Right now, an error is thrown if I try to write a class instance
to Firestore. To get around this, I've created a utility `get_database_version` method that copies
a class instance down to a plain javascript object that can be written to Firestore.
If that class instance has certain types of objects within it that Firestore
treats as special (like Dates and firebase.firestore.FieldValue's), then I
just copy the reference to those objects.

#### index.js

```
class Utils {
  static get_database_version(inst, fb) {
    if (Utils.is_function(inst)) { Error(); }

    /* make sure some firebase is defined. it could be client or admin. */
    if (!Utils.is_object(fb) || Utils.is_undefined(fb.firestore)) { Error(); }

    /* if its a basic primitive just return it. */
    if (!Utils.is_null(inst) && !Utils.is_undefined(inst) && !Utils.is_object(inst)) {
      return inst;
    }

    /* return undefined instead of nulls */
    if (Utils.is_null(inst) || Utils.is_undefined(inst)) { return undefined; }

    /* preserve Date instances for firestore writes. */
    if (inst instanceof Date) { return inst; }

    /* preserve fb.firestore.FieldValue instances for firestore writes. */
    if (inst instanceof fb.firestore.FieldValue) { return inst; }

    /* possible return object */
    var obj = {};

    /* inst must be an object at this point, so copy it, stripping it of its class. */
    for (var key in inst) {
      if (!inst.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }

      /* recurse on every value on this object */
      var res = Utils.get_database_version(inst[key], fb);

      /* only add it to the return object if its defined. */
      if (Utils.is_defined(res)) { obj[key] = res; }
    }
    /* i dont want blank objects going to firestore, so make sure it isnt. */
    return Utils.key_count(obj) ? obj : undefined;
  };

  static is_object(value) { return value !== null && (value instanceof Object); };
  static is_function(value) { return typeof value === 'function'; };
  static is_defined(value) { return typeof value !== 'undefined'; };
  static is_undefined(value) { return !Utils.is_defined(value); };
  static is_null(some_var) { return some_var === null; };
  static key_count(some_object) {
    if (!Utils.is_object(some_object)) { throw Error('must pass in an object!'); }
    return Object.keys(some_object).length;
  };
};

module.exports = Utils;
```

One sample input/output:

```
var obj = {
  a: undefined,
  b: 55,
  c: {
    d: {},
    e: {
      f: 10
    }
  }
};
console.log(Utils.get_database_version(new Foo(obj), firebase))

//output is an object stripped of Foo
//{
//  b: 55,
//  c: {
//    e: {
//      f: 10
//    }
//  }
//}
```

Comment: What your specific use case for needing to perform this check in any environment?

Comment: Right now I cannot write a class instance to firestore. I have to copy it to a bare Object in order for a firestore error not to be thrown. Thats fine unless that instance contains special objects like FieldValue's. In that case, during the copy process, I have to ask if an object is an instance of FieldValue; if that is the case, I wont touch it. And this has to work for both environments because i use this copy method in a utility class that is utilized by frontend/backend. If you would like to see the method i can post it.

Comment: So you're trying to programmatically query each property to determine if it can be serialized, and skipping the ones that can't be?

Comment: sounds like it. Ive added context for the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are changing the return value for `FieldValue.delete()` and `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to be in fact instances of FieldValue. This should be part of the next release for the Firestore Node SDK.

That being said, this is an implementation detail and the return type of `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and `FieldValue.delete()` should not affect how users interact with the Node SDK. I would recommend that you use your own types instead of relying on any undocumented behavior in our SDKs.

Speaking of undocumented behavior, a quick fix would be to compare the objects returned by `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and `FieldValue.delete()` directly. A check such as `userData === FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` guarantees that you can directly pass 'userData' to Firestore.